# Al usar extends de jade, ¿es ajax o simula ser ajax?

Tags: ajax, express, jade

Por ejemplo hago el render de esta vista:

```
 html
  head
  body
   form(action="/buscar" method="POST")
    label(for="nombre") Nombre
    input(type="text" name="nombre")
    input(type="submit")
   block contenido
    h1 usuarios
```

Despues en otra ruta se carga esta otra vista pero como solo cambia una parte de esta, esa es mi duda de si es ajax o realmente esta cargando todo

```
extends ./index.jade
block contenido
 for dato in datos
  li #{dato.nombre}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes una confusión de conceptos. Jade es una librería para escribir vistas de forma tal de evitar la repetición de HTML (abrir y cerrar etiquetas) y obligar a dar más orden al código (mediante las tabulaciones).

Para utilizarla, esta es procesada a nivel de servidor y genera código HTML el cual es entregado al cliente una vez procesado.

Ahora `extends` es una construcción de Jade, mediante la cual puedes extender una vista (que funciona como template) para así reutilizar la mayor cantidad de código

A modo de ejemplo:

```
// vista layout.jade
doctype html
html
  head
    block title
      title Default title
  body
    block content
```

Aquí defines dos `block`'s : Uno para el título (`title`, con valor por defecto `title Default title`) y otro para el contenido (`content`).

Luego, al extender de esta vista:

```
// vista article.jade
extends ./layout.jade
block title
  title Article Title

block content
  h1 My Article
```

le indicas que `block title` tiene el contenido `title Article Title` y el `block content` tiene el contenido `h1 My Article`.

Así, tienes un solo `layout` que es común para todas las posibles vistas de tu aplicación/web y solo modificas en un lugar.

Y finalmente, no, no es AJAX, está procesando a nivel de servidor el archivo `article.jade` y entregando como HTML al cliente.

---

Te recomiendo leer [la documentación](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/)

Answer (score 1):

Lo está cargando todo, los extends en jade son muy útiles para incluir un contenido que se repita en todas las páginas.
Como por ejemplo el header o el footer que siempre se repite en todas las páginas.